# How to develop netfilter queue in CentOS 6?

Tags: c, centos, netfilter

I can't find a package that would provide "libnetfilter_queue/libnetfilter_queue.h" for CentOS 6.3. (The header file that would provide struct nfq_data, struct nfq_q_handle...) Not even in the EPEL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Get the latest versions for netfilter's git repository:

```
$git clone git://git.netfilter.org/libnfnetlink.git /* needed for dependency */

$git clone git://git.netfilter.org/libnetfilter_queue.git
```

move to `nfnetilink`'s directory and issue following command:

```
$./autogen.sh
$./configure --prefix=/usr
$make
$sudo make install
```

Do the same for `netfilter_queue`.

Test  your installation:

```
$gcc <libnetfilter_queue>/ustils/nfqnl_test.c -o nftest -lnfnetlink -lnetfilter_queue
```

verify dynamic linking:

```
[root@s1 utils]# ldd nftest 
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff47dd1000)
    libnetfilter_queue.so.1 => /usr/lib/libnetfilter_queue.so.1 (0x00007f5de5a34000)
    libnfnetlink.so.0 => /usr/lib/libnfnetlink.so.0 (0x00007f5de582d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003c96000000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003c95c00000)
```

EDIT:

Regarding packages:

```
yum search netfilter
```

returned this :

```
libnetfilter_conntrack.i686 : Netfilter conntrack userspace library
libnetfilter_conntrack.x86_64 : Netfilter conntrack userspace library
libnetfilter_conntrack-devel.i686 : Netfilter conntrack userspace library
libnetfilter_conntrack-devel.x86_64 : Netfilter conntrack userspace library
libnfnetlink.i686 : Netfilter netlink userspace library
libnfnetlink.x86_64 : Netfilter netlink userspace library
libnfnetlink-devel.i686 : Netfilter netlink userspace library
libnfnetlink-devel.x86_64 : Netfilter netlink userspace library
```

I'm on 6.2 with epel, rpmforge, rpmfusion enabled.

Comment: Thanks, Aftnix, that's very useful, and certainly will be useful for somebody who wants to compile it himself. But my question was regarding packages.

So, can you confirm that no package exists?

Comment: Regarding edit: this is all good, it's netfilter, but *without* libnetfilter_queue. What does 'repoquery --whatprovides "*/libnetfilter_queue.h"' say on your system?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to download libnetfilter_queue-1.0.2 and libnfnetlink-1.0.1 src rpms from a Fedora repo and rebuild them for RHEL6/CentOS6.